# How to add toolbar to the sencha touch 2 list item?

Tags: sencha-touch

I have sencha touch 2 list , i want to add toolbar to the left of each list item . Is it possible if so how? I referred this link : http://www.sencha.com/blog/dive-into-dataview-with-sencha-touch-2-beta-2, But in my case i have to add toolbar .
It must be like :

```
toolbar-list item text-closure icon 
toolbar-list item text-closure icon 
toolbar-list item text-closure icon 
toolbar-list item text-closure icon
```

Comment: I'm not sure you're using the right components here. A toolbar needs to either be very vertical or very long and I can't see how that would be if it's stuck on the left of a list item!

Comment: ok..take button as example. I just want to add sub components for list item,not only html

Answer (score 0):

You can look [DataItem documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.component.DataItem). Here the code of example:

```
Ext.define('MyDataItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.component.DataItem',
    alias: 'widget.mydataitem',
    config: {
        padding: 10,
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox'
        },
        defaults: {
            margin: 5
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Val1'
        }, {
            xtype: 'component',
            flex: 1,
            html: 'val2',
            itemId: 'textCmp'
        }]
    },
    updateRecord: function(record) {
        var me = this;

        me.down('button').setText(record.get('val1'));
        me.down('#textCmp').setHtml(record.get('val2'));

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

DataItem extends from container. So you can add any component on it. Included [Toolbar](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.Toolbar). Add your toobar in the items array with option `docked: 'left'`.